# I have a lot of repetitive javascript code and would like help cleaning it up

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have created regular expressions that are to be validated with inline validation for a generic form that has name, email, address etc.

Each input has a blur function that is to be executed depending on what regex is being called, but within each blur function a few things need to happen as follows:

-If nothing is entered, do nothing

-If the value entered corresponds to the necessary regex and is correct, show a checkmark

-If the value entered **does not** correspond to the necessary regex, show an error and show a red X

Please see code where within each if, else if, and else is using the same code repetitively. Is there a way I can create variables or a function so that I do not have to keep on repeating the code?

Below is some of the code that I currently have. It works beautifully, I just feel like there is a simpler/cleaner way of executing it so that it is not so repetitive. I am new to javascript so anything will be greatly appreciated!

```
//validate name
function validateName(name) { 
  var reName = /^[^0-9!@#$%^&*()]+$/
return reName.test(name);
};

//validate address
function validateLetterNum(letnum) {
  var reAddress = /^[a-zA-Z\s\d\/.]*\d[a-zA-Z\s\d\/.]*$/
return reAddress.test(letnum);
};



//name validation (first and last)
$(".validName").blur(function(){
  var name = $(this).val();
  var nameCount = name.length;
  console.log(name + " " + nameCount);
    if (nameCount === 0 || nameCount == " "){
      console.log("nothing was entered");
      $(this).parent().find(".error").hide();
    }
    else if (validateName(name) && nameCount >= 2){
      console.log("good!");
        // return correct;
        $(this).parent().find(".error").fadeOut();
        $(this).parent().find(".correct").fadeIn();
        $(this).parent().find(".incorrect").hide();  
    } else {
      console.log("NOT good");
        $(this).parent().find(".error").show();
        $(this).parent().find(".correct").hide();
        $(this).parent().find(".incorrect").fadeIn();
    }
});

//address validation
$(".validLetNum").blur(function(){
  var letnum = $(this).val();
  var letnumCount = letnum.length;
    if (letnumCount === 0 || letnumCount == " "){
      console.log("nothing was entered");
      $(this).parent().find(".error").hide();
    }
    else if (validateLetterNum(letnum)) {
      console.log("letnum is good!");
      $(this).parent().find(".error").hide();
      $(this).parent().find(".correct").fadeIn();
      $(this).parent().find(".incorrect").hide();
    } else {
        console.log("letnum is NOT good");
        $(this).parent().find(".error").show();
        $(this).parent().find(".correct").hide();
        $(this).parent().find(".incorrect").fadeIn();
    }
});
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put in a function and call it with this and ['fadeOut', 'fadeIn', 'hide'] as example (this works only when the order is fixed)

```
function foo(t, fn) {
    $(t).parent().find(".error")[fn[0]]();     //.fadeOut();
    $(t).parent().find(".correct")[fn[1]]();   //.fadeIn();
    $(t).parent().find(".incorrect")[fn[2]](); //.hide();
}
```

An other solution would be call with this and an object `{ '.error': 'fadeOut', '.correct': 'fadeIn', '.incorrect': 'hide' }`

```
function foo(t, o) {
    var i;
    for (i in o) {
        $(t).parent().find(i)[o[i]]();
    }
}
```

your sample with the replaced parts as comments

```
//name validation (first and last)
$(".validName").blur(function () {
    var name = $(this).val();
    var nameCount = name.length;
    console.log(name + " " + nameCount);
    if (nameCount === 0 || nameCount == " ") {
        console.log("nothing was entered");
        $(this).parent().find(".error").hide();
    }
    else if (validateName(name) && nameCount >= 2) {
        console.log("good!");
        // return correct;
        foo(this, { '.error': 'fadeOut', '.correct': 'fadeIn', '.incorrect': 'hide' });
        //$(this).parent().find(".error").fadeOut();
        //$(this).parent().find(".correct").fadeIn();
        //$(this).parent().find(".incorrect").hide();
    } else {
        console.log("NOT good");
        foo(this, { '.error': 'show', '.correct': 'hide', '.incorrect': 'fadeIn' });
        //$(this).parent().find(".error").show();
        //$(this).parent().find(".correct").hide();
        //$(this).parent().find(".incorrect").fadeIn();
    }
});

//address validation
$(".validLetNum").blur(function () {
    var letnum = $(this).val();
    var letnumCount = letnum.length;
    if (letnumCount === 0 || letnumCount == " ") {
        console.log("nothing was entered");
        $(this).parent().find(".error").hide();
    }
    else if (validateLetterNum(letnum)) {
        console.log("letnum is good!");
        foo(this, { '.error': 'hide', '.correct': 'fadeIn', '.incorrect': 'hide' });
        //$(this).parent().find(".error").hide();
        //$(this).parent().find(".correct").fadeIn();
        //$(this).parent().find(".incorrect").hide();
    } else {
        console.log("letnum is NOT good");
        foo(this, { '.error': 'show', '.correct': 'hide', '.incorrect': 'fadeIn' });
        //$(this).parent().find(".error").show();
        //$(this).parent().find(".correct").hide();
        //$(this).parent().find(".incorrect").fadeIn();
    }
});

function foo(t, o) { //change function name to an appropriate name
    var i;
    for (i in o) {
        $(t).parent().find(i)[o[i]]();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @nina-scholz for your quick response. As I am new, I am having a hard time understanding how this would be written out in relation to the class the function is referring to. Would I only call the [fn0] [fn1] [fn2] within the if / else statements? Would you mind elaborating further including the if/else if/else?

Comment: i replaced the [fn0] with the correct way of calling it is now [...] the bracket notation of properties, you can write foo.bar or foo['bar']. inside the brackets it is a  array call with index so fn[0] for example. together its the bracket notation and an array element [fn[0]]. but in the meantime i would recommend version 2, which is mor versatile, becaus if you have more or less three parts to process it will be the one with the best possibillities.

Comment: @Marcie, please have a look.

Comment: Wow! Than you @nina-scholz for all of your help!! It works, I very much appreciate it! I'm going to take a hard look at what is happening here and hopefully be able to write something like this on my own soon. Again - thank you!

Comment: Hello Nina, I have an additional question in regards to this code here: